# Multiple if/else on list comprehensions

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I am trying to learn list comprehensions and using conditions on an iterable. I don't understand how my `if`/`else` condition is working on this list. Which `if` or `else` is working first and printing?

```py
num1 = [5, 10, 15]
num2 = [i**2 if i == 10 else i - 5 if i < 7 else i + 5 for i in num1]
print(num2)
```

Output:

```py
[0, 100, 20]
```

Comment: Ternary expressions in Python can be understood easier with parens: `val1 if cond1 else (val2 if cond2 else (val3 if cond3))`. A ternary expression must always have a return value.

Comment: Yeeeeaaah, that's exactly why you should never write code like this. At the very least this should use explicit parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Nested ternaries are *never* a good idea.

Comment: But explaining what's actually confusing you *is* a good idea. I would posit that "I don't understand" is not a valid question by itself.

Comment: Since comprehensions can include carriage returns, if you add them to your code following each `else` and the `[` and then before the `for` and the `]` you should get a presentation that is a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is not a list comprehension with conditionals (which filters out some elements of the comprehension), but a post-expression conditional of the form

```
x = A if (condition) else B
```

This assigns A if (condition) is true, otherwise it assigns B. (The syntax is a little confusing to look at, it must be admitted, but even Python is not always perfect.) You've managed to stack two of these inside each other, like this:

```
i**2 if i == 10 else (i-5 if i < 7 else i+5)
```

Reading from the right: The expression `(i-5 if i < 7 else i+5)` will give you `i-5` if `i<7`, else you get `i+5`. Whatever value this is, it is included in the comprehension whenever `i==10` is false (so, for the first and third list element).

Note that this construction has nothing to do with a list comprehension; you can use it anywhere (as long as `i` is defined).

```
i = 31
x = i**2 if i == 10 else (i-5 if i < 7 else i+5)
```

For comparison, here is a real conditional list comprehension: The comprehension will remove values that are equal to 10, leaving you with two elements in the result. I think this is the construction you set out to understand.

```
num3 = [ i**2 for i in num1 if i != 10 ]
```

Comment: Your answer just cleared and solved my problem so easily. Thank you for sharing. As I am a complete beginner i didn't think that way. Again thank you sir.

Comment: You are welcome! And welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

To actually understand how that nested ternary is working, you can write the equivalent branching statement:

```py
num2 = []
for i in num1:
    val = i
    if i == 10:
        val **= 2
    elif i < 7:
        val -= 5
    else:
        val += 5
    num2.append(val)
```

Note that no matter what `i` is, `val` is always assigned a value. This is a requirement for ternary expressions.

In general a ternary expression follows the form

```py
x = expr_if_true if some_condition else expr_if_false
```

Which is equivalent to

```py
if some_condition:
    x = expr_if_true
else:
    x = expr_if_false
```

Notice that `expr_if_true` and `expr_if_false` can be *any valid Python expression*, including other ternary expressions. This is the mechanism by which ternary expressions can nest, and this works specifically because ternary expressions *always* have a return value.

All that said, it's a *terrible* way to write code. Ternary expressions should be limited to a single level, MAYBE one level of nesting if it can be written concisely and read easily.